# Blocking special characters from being entered as input in PHP

Tags: php, character, special-characters

How would I go about blocking special characters being used in fields? If someone types a special character into the field a message should pop up on the side saying "you can't use it."

This is the kind of format I've been displaying my errors in:

```
if (empty($_POST["firstname"]))
{
    $errors['firstname'] = "Please Enter Your First Name";
}
elseif(strpos($_POST['firstname'], '/') !== false)
{
    $errors['firstname'] = 'Cannot use /';
}
```

As you can see, I have put an error in for a `/`, but I need it for all special characters.

Comment: You could use regex to check if input is valid, **[demo](http://regex101.com/r/bY7qU0)**.

Answer (score 1):

The list of invalid characters could be generated in a regular expression. In the following I am "disallowing" question marks and forward slashes.

```
<?php
$_POST['firstname'] = "Sam?uel/";

if (empty($_POST["firstname"])){

    $errors['firstname'] = "Please Enter Your First Name";

}elseif(preg_match_all("/[(?\/)]/i",$_POST['firstname'],$matches)){ // list of invalid characters

    #echo '<pre>',print_r($matches),'</pre>';
    $invalid_characters = implode(",",$matches[0]);
    $errors['firstname'] = 'Cannot use '.$invalid_characters;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a regex that strips all illegal characters and compare that to the original string. If they are not the same, illegal characters were used.

Something like:

```
$new_value = preg_replace("/[^\w]+/", "", $value);
if ($new_value !== $value)
{
   // illegal characters were used
}
```

Note that I am using a negated character class, in this case only allowing word characters and replacing all non-word characters with nothing.

Comment: whereabouts would i put this?

Comment: @user2965175 Where you have it right now, `$value` would be your `POST` variable.

Comment: @user2965175 You're welcome. Please don't forget to mark any of the answers as accepted if it worked for you.